# Problems with setting constant bitrate by using avconv

Tags: avconv

I have troubles with setting constant output bitrate. Every time I try I am getting same bitrate as input (I wanna downrate the file)

As input I have MPEG2/MPEG-A file.mpg with VBR 10Mb
As output I want MPEG2/MPEG-A file.ts with CBR 8Mb

```
avconv -i file.mpg -codec copy -b 8M -maxrate 8M -minrate 8M -bufsize 4M -f mpegts file.ts
```

Is there something wrong there? Can you suggest me better parameters so I can get better output quality?

Answer (score 3):

`-codec copy` tells avconv to just copy the first video, audio and subtitle bitstream of the input to the output. There will be no re-encoding, so any of `-b`, `-maxrate`, `-minrate` or `-bufsize` don't make sense.

So:

1. Remove `-codec copy`.
2. Use `-b:v` instead of `-b` since `-b` alone is ambiguous and could refer to both video and audio.
3. Copy the audio stream with `-c:a copy`.

In essence:

```
avconv -i file.mpg -b:v 8M -maxrate 8M -minrate 8M -bufsize 4M -c:a copy -f mpegts file.ts
```

Comment: Alright that's was confused me a lot I thought their is away to downscale video bit/rate without re-encoding ,

Comment: You cannot scale a video without re-encoding, actually.